# want footer to stay at bottom, but not absolute

Tags: html, asp.net, css, sticky-footer

am making a website, and have a wrapper on the footer, i want the footer as sticky footer, but when i minimise the screen and make it smaller the footer overtakes the content and header.

```
    #footerWrapper {
 height: 177px;
 bottom: 0;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 }
```

This does what i want as it makes the footer go to the bottom of the page regardless of what size the screen is. however when i minimise the screen and move it up it stays absolute hence staying in that 1 page.

as i would want it to stay on the page rather than the footer being absolute.

any ideas.

Comment: Use `margin-top` on the footer and give it a percentage, for example i have `margin-top:20%` and it works great. Also change `position` to `relative`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to keep the footer sticky and not overtake the header by using z-index. Just give the higher DIVs higher z-indexes.

```
    #headWrapper {
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        position: relative;
    }
    #headWrapper {
        z-index: 2;
    height: 160px;
        /* width: 960px; */
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: url(/images/PageImages/homeHeadBack.png) repeat-x;
    }

    #footerWrapper {
        background: url(/images/PageImages/footerBack.png) repeat-x;
        height: 177px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

Please note that #headWrapper needs to specify position:relative.
I think you may start from this. Worked on Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this, and it works fine, on mobiles too ...

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    padding:10px;
    background:#5ee;
}
#content {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:80px; /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#ee5;
}
```

source:

http://www.cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/

demo:

http://www.cssreset.com/demos/layouts/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/

Comment: cant have footer absolute

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#footerWrapper{
    position: fixed;
}

#contentWrapper{
    margin-bottom: 177px; // height of the footer
}
```

Comment: yeah i see what you are doing. but the problem is not everyone browser is the same size, when i set 177px the footer is not at the bottom.

Comment: To prevent the footer from overlaying on the content i gave a margin-bottom for the content section, which is the height of the footer. This will show the best result. But when it comes to responsive, yes this is not good. I think in that case you will have to change the margin-bottom from pixels to percentage in media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I'm not positive but I think I understand what you're trying to accomplish

```
#footerWrapper {
   background: url(/images/PageImages/footerBack.png) repeat-x;
   height: 177px;
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   bottom: 0px;
}

#contentWrapper {
   background: url(/images/PageImages/contentTopBack.png) no-repeat center top;
   min-height: 208px;
   margin-bottom: 177px;
}
```

If that doesn't fix it than I don't understand what you're aiming for.

Comment: same problem. because the bottom is set to : 0px, that means it will still go up

Comment: Well if you don't want it to move up with the page why don't you just not bother with fixed, or absolute? let it be a part of you pages flow.

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css" ... />

</head>

<body>

    <div class="wrapper">

        <p>Your website content here.</p>

        <div class="push"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="footer">

        <p>Copyright (c) 2014</p>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
margin: 0;
}
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -4em;
}
.footer, .push {
height: 4em;
}
```

for more [information](http://rosanko.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-use-css-sticky-footer-on-your.html).